# Laravel routes condition based on which path, how to get the right path

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatables

My Routes:

routes for different views

```php
Route::get('/participants', 'DatatablesController@getIndex')->name('participants');
Route::get('/completed', 'DatatablesController@getIndex')->name('completed');
Route::get('/failed', 'DatatablesController@getIndex')->name('failed');
//route to get data to views
Route::get('participants_dt', 'DatatablesController@getData')->name('get.survey_requests');
```

Controller:

```
public function getData()
{
    $request = Request::path();
    error_log($request);
    // $request returns participant_dt currently.
    // I want it to return based on which view I'm on.

    if ($request == 'participants') {
        //return query
    } elseif ($request == 'complete') {
        //return complete
    } else {
        //return failed
    }
}
```

Is there a way to name my route based on which route it's on? e.g. if route /complete is selected then the route participants_dt will be named complete?

Comment: What do you mean which view you're on? You're not on any view!! an `<a href="/participants_dt"></a>` tag on the view is not any different from accessing through direct URL like `localhost:8000/participants_dt`, there's no way you can tell the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your views are on different routes, you can use the previous URL to determine which view the request came from

```php
public function getData()
{
    $request = url()->previous(); // Get previous URL
    $request = parse_url($request)['path']; // Remove domain name
    $request = ltrim($request, '/'); // Remove first slash
    error_log($request);
    dd($request); // Returns the route where the view is (ex: participants)
    if ($request == 'participants') {
        //return query
    } elseif ($request == 'complete') {
        //return complete
    } else {
        //return failed
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, your routes should go to different methods within the controller. For example:

```
Route::get('/completed', 'DatatablesController@getCompleted')->name('completed');
Route::get('/failed', 'DatatablesController@getFailed')->name('failed');
```

And then in your controller:

```
public function getCompleted() {
    $this->getData('completed');
}

public function getFailed() {
   $this->getData('failed');
}

protected function getData($status_type = 'participants')
{
    if ($status_type == 'participants') {
        //return query
    } elseif ($status_type == 'complete') {
        //return complete
    } else {
        //return failed
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this and it never changed the $status_type, only got it to show the query if status_type was participants.